# Diff, Patch and Reverse-patch in Java

Tags: java, diff, patch, lcs

I am looking for a java util which can create a diff between two java objects, which can be nested and contain arrays etc. 
The util should also have the capability to apply the diff (a.k.a patch) on the original object and also remove the diff from it.

I got one in JS: https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch.
However, it would be nice if there is one existing in Java already.

Please also note that the tool should implement LCS, and array-comparison should be based on a hash-function (customizable) instead of a verbatim (line-by-line) comparison, which means it should take care of array-moves etc.

Diff can either take XML/JSON-converted java objects

Answer (score 0):

So you wanna compare/"patch" instances of the same class right?
Take a look here:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/
You could use BeanComparator and BeanUtils classes.

Comment: I didn't get the idea. Could you give us some examples?

Answer (score 0):

http://javers.org can calculate a nice diff between thwo complex Java object graphs, but can't apply it back to revert changes. Still, you can retrieve a prevoius versions  of audited object (as snapshots) from Repository